# Swift: Failing to set a [String] through a segue using the sender

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

Good day. I'm creating my first own app and have ran into an issue. I have a AR scene with clickable stuff which when you touch them a segue triggers into a ViewController and sets that view controllers labels and textview depending on what was touch on screen.

Explanations: 1. CaseViewController is the target view controller. 2. the "artNews" and "politicalNews" are string arrays in which I've written 3 strings, they are defined and are never nil.

Question: I get a crash due to the segueInputText being nil. Why does it become nil and how do I correct it?

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! CaseViewController
    destinationVC.segueInputText = sender as? [String]

    print("\(String(describing: sender))")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView),
        let hitNode = sceneView?.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil).first?.node,
        let nodeName = hitNode.name
        else { return }

    if nodeName == imageNameArray[0] {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CaseViewController", sender: artNews)

    } else {
        print("Found no node connected to \(nodeName)")
        return
    }

    if nodeName == imageNameArray[1] {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CaseViewController", sender: politicalNews)

    } else {
        print("Found no node connected to \(nodeName)")
        return
    }
```

the CaseViewController has UILabels and UITextViews connected and this:

```
    var segueInputText : [String]? {
    didSet {
        setupText()
    }
}

    func setupText() {

    // Why are these values nil? 
    testLabel.text = segueInputText![0]
    ingressLabel.text = segueInputText![1]
    breadLabel.text = segueInputText![2]

    testLabel.reloadInputViews()
    ingressLabel.reloadInputViews()
    breadLabel.reloadInputViews() //breadLabel is a UITextView
}
```

Thank you for reading my question!
Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `didSet` observer in this case. It will never work.

In `setupText()` `IBOutlets` are accessed which are not connected yet at the moment `prepare(for` is called.

---

Remove the observer

```
var segueInputText : [String]?
```

and call `setupText` in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupText()
}
```

Comment: "Don't use*r* the" - probably a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `didSet` block as when you set the array inside prepare , observe triggers and the lbl is still `nil`

**OR**

```
func setupText() {
   if testLabel == nil { // if one is nil then all of them too
     return 
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should call `setupText` from within `viewWillAppear` instead. Then, you can also skip the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

At the very moment when you do this:

```
destinationVC.segueInputText = sender as? [String]
```

the destination view controller has not yet loaded hence none of the outlets are connected so accessing any of them will crash your app as they are still nil.

You will have to assign any of the values you’d like to pass to the destination controller to a property and assign this property’s value to the the corresponding outlet in `viewDidLoad`. This way you make sure all outlets have connected.

For the same reason don’t use a property observer to assign the property’s value to any of the labels as this would happen, again, before the view controller had a chance to load…